# Recommendation for Python Code Analyzer

Tags: library, python, code-analysis

I am seeking recommendation library/software for analyzing python source code statically.

The expecting results from the library are

- What are the third party libraries used in the code
- What are the third party methods calls used in the code
- What are the classes, enums used inside the code from third party libraries

Recommendations are highly appreciated.